# Chemfig breaks tabular

Tags: tables, chemfig

I tried using `\chemfig` in a tabular. The document compiles if the `tabular` has one line, but not two. It also compiles if I remove the opening brackets.

The error produced is

```
Missing number, treated as zero. [Na]
```

What's happening?

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{chemfig}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 [Ca] & \chemfig{Ca}\\
 [Na] & \chemfig{Na}\\
 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reading it as the optional argument to `\\`, so you just need to block that by adding e.g. `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  [Ca] & \chemfig{Ca}\\
  {}[Na] & \chemfig{Na}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: fixed tabular]

**EDIT** Add image now uploads work again.

Comment: Aha! So `chemfig` was not to blame. It irks me when I see things like `\documentclass  {article}`, but the `verbatim` package went out of its way to allow `\end    {verbatim}`. Is it proper practice to do so?

Comment: @Kurzd I don't do it and I didn't do it in my answer here as far as I can tell. I think it is easier to keep the thing ended with the `\end` etc. However, technically, the macro `\documentclass` or `\end` or whatever gobbles the space, so I guess you could do it, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Kurzd I don't really understand the question since `\documentclass {article}` doesn't appear in either your post or mine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, you're not. I just thought that having `\\ ` and `[Ca] ` on different lines would be just fine which is why I asked the question on the first place. I then went on to ask if adding spaces is good practice.